# Android Surface View with Custom Size

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I am working on an OCR app with a Surface View and Google Vision API, which works fin; but the Surface View extends over the whole Display of the Device (Galaxy Grand Prime). It should only have half of the size or less, so that the recognised text can be displayed in a Text View beneath the Surface View. Although I googled a lot, I couldn´t solve this problem and would appreciate any support and advice, thanks!

The Main Activity:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    SurfaceView mCameraView;
    TextView mTextView;
    CameraSource mCameraSource;


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int requestPermissionID = 101;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mCameraView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        startCameraSource();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != requestPermissionID) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got unexpected permission result: " + requestCode);
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            return;
        }

        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                mCameraSource.start(mCameraView.getHolder());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    private void startCameraSource() {

        //Create the TextRecognizer
        final TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

        if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Detector dependencies not loaded yet");
        } else {

            //Initialize camerasource to use high resolution and set Autofocus on.
            mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                    .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                    .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                    .build();

            /**
             * Add call back to SurfaceView and check if camera permission is granted.
             * If permission is granted we can start our cameraSource and pass it to surfaceView
             */
            mCameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    try {

                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    requestPermissionID);
                            return;
                        }
                        mCameraSource.start(mCameraView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    mCameraSource.stop();
                }
            });

            //Set the TextRecognizer's Processor.
            textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
                @Override
                public void release() {
                }

                /**
                 * Detect all the text from camera using TextBlock and the values into a stringBuilder
                 * which will then be set to the textView.
                 * */
                @Override
                public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
                    final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                    if (items.size() != 0 ){

                        mTextView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
                                    TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                                    stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                                }
                                mTextView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                                        // Start NewActivity.class
                                        String recognizedText = mTextView.getText().toString();
                                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                                        i.putExtra("recognized Text", recognizedText);


                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            String recognizedText = mTextView.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("recognized Text", recognizedText);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/txt_message"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```